# Is it Safe to Set PHP Max Execution Time to 600?

Tags: php, vtiger

I'm installing a newer version of vTiger CRM. One of the prerequisites is editing php.ini **max_execution_time** to 600 instead of the default 30. This gap in settings has me questioning if it's safe to increase the execution time? Especially by so much. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see nothing speaking against it, as long as this is for maintenance scripts only  - which I assume it is. Some database maintenance or import scripts may take this much time. The CRM in everyday use, though, should not.

Just bear this in mind, from the PHP manual on [**max_execution_time**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time):

> Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe after all vTiger CRM don't want to put anyone at risk and also retain its usage amongst users. **[More here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php)**.